# Selecting similar DOM elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome plugin and I am testing it with [ycombinator news](https://news.ycombinator.com)

I am able to get the CSS Selector of the news links. Below are the css selectors for first three links

```
html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > a
html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(3) > a
html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(3) > a
```

Now i want to select all other similar links using first two or three css selectors. It can be any other element also not only link.
Is there any approach in jquery with which this can be achieved.

Comment: Can you share HTML markup sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can the multiple selector operator (",") : https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$("html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > a, 
html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(3) > a, 
html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(3) > a")
```

Or, more properly :

```
$("html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody").find("tr:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(4), tr:nth-child(7)").find("td:nth-child(3) > a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~`:

```
html > body > ... > td:nth-child(3) > a ~ p
```

this will select all the paragraphs inside the parent of `a` or i would say the sibling elements `p`

Answer (score 0):

As i understand question, you want as CSS rule:

```
html > body > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3n+1) > td:nth-child(3) > *
```

See: `tr:nth-child(3n+1)` which target the 1,4,7,10, etc...
*&* `> *` to get all type of child, not only anchor

Comment: I was looking for a generic way, such that with the help of two css selectors, taking their difference and construct a new css selector to get all the similar elements